# Freeing pointers in structs pointing to other structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Let's say I have some data structure in which structs have pointers to other structs, such as a linked list. Each element in the list would have a pointer to another element in the list

```
struct node{
  char* data;
  node* next;
};
```

When freeing the memory allocated to this structure, I am aware I need to specifically free data first, as I have to allocate memory for it specifically. But what about next? It points to another node, and I believe freeing it would free the actual node next is pointing to.

Is it enough to just free the entire node when cleaning up, or is there any way to free the pointer without freeing the struct it is pointing to?

Comment: Are you deleting one item or the whole list?  Either way, `free()` frees only the pointer it is passed; it does not know about or free any data that the structure pointed at contains.

Comment: I don't get it like in linked list also why you need to allocate memory for `next` ?

Comment: Don't think about freeing the pointers -- think about freeing the blocks of memory you allocated.  Balance each allocation with a free once the block isn't needed anymore... there could be a hundred pointers to the same block and you'd still only need to free it once, or you could have pointers to things you didn't dynamically allocate that you don't need to free at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no thing like *freeing a pointer*, you can only free *memory* a pointer points to -- so if you want to delete a single element of a linked list, you have to update the `next` pointer of the previous item so it points to the `next` of the element you want to delete (which may be `NULL`) before deleting it.

```
void deleteNode(struct node **list, struct node *element)
{
    /* first node? */
    if (element == *list)
    {
        *list = element->next;
        free(element->data);
        free(element);
        /* now list points to the second element, if any */
    }
    else
    {
        /* find previous node */
        struct node *p = *list;
        while (p->next != element) p = p->next;

        /* adjust next pointer */
        p->next = element->next;
        free(element->data);
        free(element);
    }
}
```

Note that using a singly-linked list is not suitable for big lists with random deletes because you have to search the list from the beginning each time.

For deleting a *whole* linked list, there's an iterative and a recursive approach, but I'm not showing code here because as I understood your question, this is not what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 4):

It depends how you are building the structure up in memory. Any `malloc` must be balanced with `free`. Once the pointed-to `next` node is freed, it is no longer valid.

```
// create root
node* n1 = calloc(1, sizeof(node));

// create/link another node
n1->next = calloc(1, sizeof(node));

// destroy/unlink 2nd node
free(n1->next);
n1->next = NULL;

// destroy 1st node
free(n1);
```